Issues with Closed Polygons: Loop is not valid
I've been encountering an issue while working with spatial data in R. Specifically, I'm getting an error when trying to calculate centroids for my geometries using the st_centroid function from the sf package. The error message is as follows:
Error in st_centroid.sfc(st_geometry(x)) :
not implemented for objects of class sfc_GEOMETRY
Caused by error in wk_handle.wk_wkb():
! Loop 7 is not valid: Edge 185 crosses edge 187
Backtrace:

shapefile_data %>% ...
sf:::st_centroid.sfc(geometry)
s2::s2_centroid(x)
sf:::as_s2_geography.sfc(x)
sf:::st_as_s2.sfc(x, ..., oriented = oriented)
s2:::as_s2_geography.WKB(st_as_binary(x), ..., oriented = oriented)
s2::s2_geog_from_wkb(x, oriented = oriented, check = check)
wk:::wk_handle.wk_wkb(...)

I've tried using st_make_valid to ensure all geometries are valid, but it hasn't resolved the issue. Here's a simplified version of my code:
library(sf)
library(dplyr)

# Load shapefile data
shapefile_path <- "/path/to/shapefile.shp"
shapefile_data <- st_read(shapefile_path)

shapefile_data <- st_make_valid(shapefile_data)

invalid_geometries <- which(!st_is_valid(shapefile_data))
if (length(invalid_geometries) > 0) {
  shapefile_data <- st_make_valid(shapefile_data)
}

shapefile_data <- st_transform(shapefile_data, crs = "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84")

shapefile_data <- shapefile_data %>%
  mutate(centroid = st_centroid(geometry),
         lon = st_coordinates(centroid)[, 1],
         lat = st_coordinates(centroid)[, 2])
And the map is look wired too:


Despite these steps, the error still persists. I'm not sure how to proceed to make sure each of polygon is close. I would greatly appreciate any suggestions or solutions to handle this issue.

Your error occurs because your data are an S2 object, e.g. spherical coordinates (NAD27). In order to avoid the error, either stop R treating S2 objects as spherical, or project your data to planar coordinates and then project them back to NAD27.
To demonstrate, using the your simplified version of your code:
library(sf)
library(rnaturalearth)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

# Example data
world <- ne_countries() %>%
  st_transform("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84")

world <- world %>%
  mutate(centroid = st_centroid(geometry),
         lon = st_coordinates(centroid)[, 1],
         lat = st_coordinates(centroid)[, 2])

# Error in `stopifnot()`:
#   ℹ In argument: `centroid = st_centroid(geometry)`.
# Caused by error in `wk_handle.wk_wkb()`:
#   ! Loop 0 is not valid: Edge 0 crosses edge 78
# Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

# Turn off S2
sf_use_s2(FALSE)

world <- world %>%
  mutate(centroid = st_centroid(geometry),
         lon = st_coordinates(centroid)[, 1],
         lat = st_coordinates(centroid)[, 2])

# Warning message:
#   There was 1 warning in `stopifnot()`.
# ℹ In argument: `centroid = st_centroid(geometry)`.
# Caused by warning in `st_centroid.sfc()`:
#   ! st_centroid does not give correct centroids for longitude/latitude data

The warning is telling you the centroids aren't exact. If you just need approximate locations, it is fine. For more precise centroids, search for an appropriate planar CRS for your area of interest, st_transform(), calculate your centroids, convert back to NAD27, then calculate your lon/lat columns. It's a good habit to turn S2 processing back on afterwards e.g.
sf_use_s2(TRUE)

